# Expectations of sums

Tags: probability-or-statistics, summation, distributions, variable-definitions

I would like to use Mathematica to derive some bounds on empirical estimators, such as $E[Y]$ where $Y = \tfrac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - X)^2$ and $X = \tfrac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

For a moment I thought this worked:

```
Expectation[Sum[X[i], {i, 1, n}], {X[i] \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p]}]

Out[*] = n p
```

However, it quickly turned out that Mathematica just considers this a single variable named `X[i]`.

I wonder if `Expectation` can be made to handle a variable number of random variables?

Comment: For fixed `n`, you can always use `Expectation[Sum[X[i], {i, 1, n}], 
 Table[X[i] \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p], {i, 1, n}]]`, naturally. I'm not sure there is a built-in way to make this work for symbolic `n`, though.

Comment: You are seeking the expectation of the $2^\text{nd}$ sample central moment, which for any distribution whose first 2 moments exist, is equal to $\frac{ (n-1)}{n} \mu _2$, where $\mu_2$ denotes the $2^\text{nd}$ population central moment (i.e. the population variance). Your problem would be more interesting/challenging if it extended outside of textbook base cases.

Comment: @wolfies I was trying to keep it simple to focus on the Mathematica code rather than the mathematics. But indeed I'm actually trying to find the variance of the sample variance. (and a few other quantities). It seems simple enough to do by hand, but tedious and easy to get wrong. (My problem is somewhat related to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196689 .)

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) to find the distribution for the sum. Assuming that the `x[i]` are independent and identically distributed

```
dist[p_, n_Integer?Positive] :=
 TransformedDistribution[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}],
  Table[x[i] \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p], {i, 1, n}]]

dist[p, #] & /@ Range[5]

(* {BernoulliDistribution[p], BinomialDistribution[2, p], 
 BinomialDistribution[3, p], BinomialDistribution[4, p], 
 BinomialDistribution[5, p]} *)
```

The [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) is then

```
seq = Mean[dist[p, #]] & /@ Range[5]

(* {p, 2 p, 3 p, 4 p, 5 p} *)
```

Generalizing,

```
mean[p_, n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]

(* n p *)
```

Similarly for the [`Variance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html)

```
variance[p_, n_] = FindSequenceFunction[
  Variance[dist[p, #]] & /@ Range[5], n]

(* n p - n p^2 *)
```

Comment: So the approach is to calculate a number of values, and then use `FindSequenceFunction` to guess a closed form? In either case, that function is a catch! I had no idea Mathematica had something like that, even if the solutions don't prove anything.

Comment: What would you do if the `x[i]` weren't independent? Say I want to find `E[Y]` as a function of the variances and covariances of the `x[i]`? (Note in this case `E[Y] = (1-1/n)\sigma^2`, so the covariances don't matter, but for `E[(Y-EY)^2]` it does.)

Comment: Look at the documentation for [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html). `TransformedDistribution[expr, {x1, x2, ...} \[Distributed] dist]` where `dist` is the multivariate distribution.